# App crashes when using Salesforce React Native SDK and Xcode 8

Tags: react-native, salesforce, xcode8

I was trying to compile a sample app with Salesforce React Native SDK 4.3 and Xcode 8. The app would build successfully, but when loading on the simulator, it would crash at the splash screen and at the following line of code:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"SFApplication", @"AppDelegate");
```

I got the following errors in the output:

**ibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

and further up

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.salesforce.security.keychainException', reason: 'writeToKeychain: Error adding keychain item: Unknown status code (-34018).'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that enabling Keychain Sharing under "Capabilities" will fix the problem. I believe this issue should be fixed with SDK 5.

[image]

Comment: ... and there was me thinking that searching for "com.salesforce.security.keychainException" would be too niche to find an answer. Thanks for bothering to post & answer! FYI we have a Stack Exchange site just for Salesforce too: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com